# Lombok ArrayObject initializing

Tags: java, json, api, lombok

I have an api body response starts with and ArrayObject, normally if my response comes as an object I dont have issue in accessing the data like in the below

```
{
"status": true,
"message": valid
"actions" {
  "start": "yes"
  "valid": "yes"
    }
}
```

For the above object I can simply create a lombok object as below

```
    @Data
    @Builder
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public class MyValidResponse {
        String status;
        string message;
        Actions actions;
        }

    @Data
    @Builder
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public class Actions {
         String start;
         String valid;
        }
```

By my Issue is when my response comes in the below

```
[
{"status": true,
"valid":"Yes"
},
{"start": true,
"valid":"No"
}
]
```

How can I access this kind of response with lombok objects

```
public static List<Result> getResult() {
     Response response = get(myAPIURL);
     return ??? HOW do I access my array of objects response in here

}
```

I tried

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class StatusResult {
    List<Result> resul;
    }


@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Result {
    boolean start;
    String valid;
    }
```

But am getting out of START_ARRAY token

Any guidance is appreciated
Thank you

Comment: in your controller declare like input DTO List<Result>

Comment: @tino89, Thank you for your reply, But I am not a developer who work with that, am just trying to access the data for test purpose,

Comment: currently I thing you have StatusResult  = your response, try changing it by List<Result> = your response

Comment: That Basically is my question, How Do I declare that List<result> with all the details in it. That REsult is an object in an Array.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jackson for JSON, enabling the `DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY` feature will allow you to support both messages that have `actions` as an object or those that have `actions` as an array.

```java
package com.stackoverflow.SO66019363;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

import java.util.List;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Singular;

class SO66019363Test {

    // @formatter:off
    static final String SINGLE ="{\n"
            + "\"status\": true,\n"
            + "\"message\": \"valid\",\n"
            + "\"actions\": {\n"
            + "  \"start\": \"yes\",\n"
            + "  \"valid\": \"yes\"\n"
            + "    }\n"
            + "}";

    static final String MULTIPLE ="{\n"
            + "\"status\": true,\n"
            + "\"message\": \"valid\",\n"
            + "\"actions\": [\n"
            + "{\"start\": true,\n"
            + "\"valid\":\"Yes\"\n"
            + "},\n"
            + "{\"start\": true,\n"
            + "\"valid\":\"No\"\n"
            + "}\n"
            + "]\n"
            + "}";
 // @formatter:on

    static final ObjectMapper OBJECT_MAPPER = new ObjectMapper()
            .enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY);

    @Test
    void test() throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException {

        MyValidResponse multiple = OBJECT_MAPPER.readValue(MULTIPLE, MyValidResponse.class);

        assertEquals(2, multiple.getActions()
                .size());

        MyValidResponse single = OBJECT_MAPPER.readValue(SINGLE, MyValidResponse.class);

        assertEquals(1, single.getActions()
                .size());

    }


    @Data
    @Builder
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    static class MyValidResponse {

        String status;

        String message;

        @Singular
        List<Actions> actions;
    }

    @Data
    @Builder
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    static class Actions {

        String start;

        String valid;
    }
}
```